# Investment balance in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm having a lot of trouble using the for loop with this. It's really confusing me, this is my code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount deposited: ");
        double principle = 0; //amount deposited
        principle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of years: ");
        int years = 0;
        years = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the interest rate as a percentage of 
        1.0: ");
        double interest;
        interest = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double balance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < years; i++)
        {
            balance = principle * Math.Pow((1 + interest),years);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Years {0}", years);
        Console.WriteLine("Balance {0}", balance);
```

How can I make it so that a table outputs?

Comment: Look at the value of `balance` and `years` [in your debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). You just recalculate the same value over and over without storing or printing anything.

Comment: And you're using `years` in the formula when you should be using `i` (or probably `i + 1`) instead.

Comment: You almost always want to use `decimal` when working with money/currency.  Also  *principal* not 'principle'

Comment: Here is a hint: if you want to print a table, then you need to print a row for each year of the investment. Let me emphasize that you must print something for each year. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Console.Write("Enter the amount deposited: ");
        double principle = 0; 
        principle = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter number of years: ");
        int years = 0;
        years = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Enter the interest rate as a percentage of 1.0: ");

        double interest;
        interest = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double balance = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Years \t Balance", years);
        for (int i = 0; i < years; i++)
        {
            balance = principle * Math.Pow((1 + interest), i);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} \t {1}", i, balance);
        }
```