# How to enter the input into the command line rather than within the code?

Tags: c#

Here is the Huffman code to compress and decompress ASCII. I want to make a command after I run a program to enter my input where then it is compressed and another command to decompress. I just know how to place my input within the code but that is not what I want. I want it within my command box.

```
internal class Program
{
    private const string Example = "this is an example for huffman encoding";

    private static void Main()
    {
        var huffman = new Huffman<char>(Example);
        List<int> encoding = huffman.Encode(Example);
        List<char> decoding = huffman.Decode(encoding);
        var outString = new string(decoding.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine(outString == Example 
            ? "Encoding/decoding worked" 
            : "Encoding/Decoding failed");

        var chars = new HashSet<char>(Example);

        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            encoding = huffman.Encode(c);
            Console.Write("{0}: ", c);

            foreach(int bit in encoding)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}", bit);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to enter the input as a command line parameter when starting the program? Or enter it into the console application's command line user interface? Or would you like to pipe it in? Or put it in a configuration file? So many choices.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56640265/investment-balance-in-c for example.

Comment: Console application's command line user interface please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you can use Console.ReadLine() to read input from the command line. If you are looking for something different, you may want to clarify your question. Example of Console.ReadLine() shown below:

```
internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Type input text here: ");
        var inputText = Console.ReadLine();
        var huffman = new Huffman<char>(inputText);
        List<int> encoding = huffman.Encode(inputText);
        List<char> decoding = huffman.Decode(encoding);
        var outString = new string(decoding.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine(outString == inputText ? "Encoding/decoding 
    worked" : "Encoding/Decoding failed");

        var chars = new HashSet<char>(inputText);
        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            encoding = huffman.Encode(c);
            Console.Write("{0}: ", c);
            foreach(int bit in encoding)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}", bit);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

More information on Console.ReadLine here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Is there a way to compress it and decompress it separately on different command lines?

Comment: I think there may be something fundamentally missing from my understanding of your question, but I think you are asking if you can compress the text, then in a separate window decompress the text? It would help to understand what you are going for, but if I had to guess, I think what you are looking for will require some sort of way to store the value taken from the input. You can write it out to a file, as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file. Then, from the other side, you would read it from this file.